# SQL - How to compare two columns in different lines?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my first question here.

How to compare two columns in different lines? The database is SQL Server 2000.

I have these data in my table:

```
id          entrance                exit
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
10000       2017-06-03 09:07:00.000 NULL
10000       NULL                    2017-06-03 11:59:00.000 
10000       NULL                    2017-06-03 12:31:00.000 
10000       2017-06-03 12:25:00.000 NULL
20000       2017-06-03 13:13:00.000 NULL
20000       NULL                    2017-06-03 17:39:00.000
```

I need to verify the difference between the entrance and the exit.

For example: the difference between first entrance (first line) and first exit (second line), after this comparison, verify between the first exit (second line) and the next entrance (third line) and so on.

How can I compare these lines? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't tell, the database is SQL 2000.

Comment: Stop everything you are doing, and upgrade to a supported version. Just some advice. It's end of life support ended over 4 years ago.

Comment: There are no "lines" in a database. The data is deemed to be unordered unless you specify something to order by. Have you any reliable ordering column (eg last updated, or an identity column)?

Comment: @scsimon I know man, but I can't do this 

Comment: @LordPeter all data are ordered by ID

Comment: Thanks for all answers! Wendy's answer and Ryszard Kozlowski's answer helped me, but Wendy's support my problem as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manufacture a row id in exact sequence.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(RowId INT IDENTITY(1,1)
, Id   INT
, Entrance   DATETIME
, [Exit] DATETIME
)
INSERT #temp VALUES(10000 , '2017-06-03 09:07:00.000', NULL)
INSERT #temp VALUES(10000 , NULL, '2017-06-03 11:59:00.000' )
INSERT #temp VALUES(10000 , NULL ,'2017-06-03 12:31:00.000' )
INSERT #temp VALUES(10000 , '2017-06-03 12:25:00.000', NULL)
INSERT #temp VALUES(20000 , '2017-06-03 13:13:00.000', NULL)
INSERT #temp VALUES(20000 , NULL ,'2017-06-03 17:39:00.000')

SELECT  a.RowId
    , a.id
    , ISNULL(a.entrance, a.[exit]) AS Entrance
    , ISNULL(b.[exit], b.Entrance) AS [Exit]
FROM #temp a
LEFT JOIN #temp b 
    ON b.Id = a.Id
    AND b.RowId = a.RowId + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it true that each row will contain either Entrance or Exit? If yes then my suggestion would be merge those column in one and use a flag. You can think of using UNION for that purpose.

Now you can write a small procedure to run from 1st row to last row and find difference between consecutive rows.

Comment: In the original data I have the entrance and the exit together. And I have a flag describing if is entrance 'E' and if is exit 'S'.

Comment: I think it best would be to write a procedure.

Comment: I think it best would be to write a procedure. Sort on Id, datetime, column (Latest first). Loop through 1st row to last row. Subtract  datetime from current row from row at top (if those have different type 'E' or 'S'). You can generate an array containing id, date, time-difference.

Comment: that's another doubt, how is the best way to loop through the data? Cursor or other way?

Comment: I would prefer CURSOR creation for this job.

Answer (score 0):

If possible you can do an "UPDATE" query when the id is already present. The id here is not uniquely identifiable.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

and then you can select:

```
select t.exit - t.entrance as difference from table t where t.id="2000"
```

And if it is still required to insert a new row every time then generate a row id during SQL as suggested in another answer by Wendy.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose using the following code. The idea is to select all rows with non null entry values (*en*), then join it with records with the same id but having exit timesamp greater than entry timestamp (*ex*). Finally, left join (*xex*) is used to ensure that there is no other row with exit timestamp between *en* and *ex*.

```
-- data stored as per original question
CREATE TABLE #tbl
(
  [id] INT NOT NULL,
  [entrance] DATETIME,
  [exit] DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO #tbl ([id], [entrance], [exit]) 
VALUES (10000, '2017-06-03 09:07:00.000', NULL);
INSERT INTO #tbl ([id], [entrance], [exit]) 
VALUES (10000, NULL, '2017-06-03 11:59:00.000');
INSERT INTO #tbl ([id], [entrance], [exit]) 
VALUES (10000, NULL, '2017-06-03 12:31:00.000');
INSERT INTO #tbl ([id], [entrance], [exit]) 
VALUES (10000, '2017-06-03 12:25:00.000', NULL);
INSERT INTO #tbl ([id], [entrance], [exit]) 
VALUES (20000, '2017-06-03 13:13:00.000', NULL);
INSERT INTO #tbl ([id], [entrance], [exit]) 
VALUES (20000, NULL, '2017-06-03 17:39:00.000');

SELECT en.id, en.[entrance], ex.[exit], 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, en.[entrance], ex.[exit]) elapsed_min
FROM #tbl en
JOIN #tbl ex ON en.id=ex.id AND ex.[exit] IS NOT NULL AND ex.[exit] > en.[entrance]
LEFT JOIN #tbl xex ON en.id=xex.id AND xex.[exit] IS NOT NULL 
AND xex.[exit] < ex.[exit] AND xex.[exit] > en.[entrance]
WHERE en.entrance IS NOT NULL AND xex.[id] IS NULL;


GO

-- data stored as per comment
CREATE TABLE #tbl2
(
  [id] INT NOT NULL,
  [type] CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  [timestamp] DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #tbl2 ([id], [type], [timestamp]) 
VALUES (10000, 'E', '2017-06-03 09:07:00.000');
INSERT INTO #tbl2 ([id], [type], [timestamp]) 
VALUES (10000, 'S', '2017-06-03 11:59:00.000');
INSERT INTO #tbl2 ([id], [type], [timestamp]) 
VALUES (10000, 'S', '2017-06-03 12:31:00.000');
INSERT INTO #tbl2 ([id], [type], [timestamp]) 
VALUES (10000, 'E', '2017-06-03 12:25:00.000');
INSERT INTO #tbl2 ([id], [type], [timestamp]) 
VALUES (20000, 'E', '2017-06-03 13:13:00.000');
INSERT INTO #tbl2 ([id], [type], [timestamp]) 
VALUES (20000, 'S', '2017-06-03 17:39:00.000');

SELECT en.id, en.[timestamp], ex.[timestamp], 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, en.[timestamp], ex.[timestamp]) elapsed_min
FROM #tbl2 en
JOIN #tbl2 ex ON en.id=ex.id AND ex.[type]='S' AND ex.[timestamp] > en.[timestamp]
LEFT JOIN #tbl2 xex ON en.id=xex.id AND xex.[type]='S' 
AND xex.[timestamp] < ex.[timestamp] AND xex.[timestamp] > en.[timestamp]
WHERE en.[type]='E' AND xex.[id] IS NULL;

GO
```